# Related spinners Android

Tags: android

I'm begginer in android. I'm working on a project. But i get very difficult to do two spinners related to each others. Actually one spinner for the country and another for the city. Instead of the country that is chosen the second spinner will show the cities.

I'v used "OnItemSelectedListener" but the " ArrayAdapter.createFromResourc​e " can't be used inside OnItemSelectedListener.
I've tried a lot of other ways but still none of them working. 
Can anybody help me Please???

(P.S. I have read and tried the other posts about this topic but it still doesn't work )
This is the code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    int spinnerId = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if (spinnerId==0){
    adaptert = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.tirana, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adaptert.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }
    else if (spinnerId==1) {
        adaptert = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.durres, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adaptert.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        }

    spinnert.setAdapter(adaptert);


                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: is the reason that createFromResource doesn't work inside the OnItemSelectedListener that you don't have access to 'this'? Try with YourActivityName.this instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AdapterViewImplementation extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    Spinner sp1; // One Spinner
    Spinner sp2;  // Another Spinner
    ArrayAdapter stateAdapter;  // Adapter for state
    ArrayAdapter cityAdapter;  // Adapter for city

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);


        stateAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(AdapterViewImplementation.this,
                R.array.state, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        stateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterViewImplementation.this);


        cityAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(AdapterViewImplementation.this,
                R.array.city, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterViewImplementation.this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(arg0 == sp1){

            sp2.setSelection(arg2);

        }else{

            sp1.setSelection(arg2);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```